# Retrieve custom permission via API

Tags: wso2, rbac, wso2-identity-server

I added a custom permission on a Service Provider via carbon console in my Identity Server.
How can I retrieve the above permission via API to leverage authorization in my Service Provider Application programmatically?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 IS support SOAP API to retrieve the service provider information. You can use this to get the customs permissions.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Using+the+Service+Provider+API#UsingtheServiceProviderAPI-getApplication

Comment: hi @senthalan thank you for your reply. Is this the best approach to programmatically check permissions in my service provider? Do I have to call this API everytime to check permission or can it be cached somewhere to avoid too many API calls? The use case is an external portal (registered as SP in wso2IS) from which I want to abstract the authorization layer( simple RBAC/ABAC). The portal is developed using spring boot. Many thanks